# Unix scipt to copy all the files except latest timestamp file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

Is there any command which will copy all the files except latest timestamp file from one directory to another in Unix.

Dir1 - file1,file2,file3, file4(new timestamp)

cp to Dir2 - file1,file2,file3 and i don't want file4 as this is a new file in Dir1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ls -1tr | tail -1` construct to get the latest file.

Then copy the files, except for the latest.

If the list of files is usually fairly short, this code could be changed
to create a list of files and then do the copy -- that would be more efficient.

```
dir2="../somewhereelse"
exception=$(ls -1tr | tail -1)
for fn in *; do
  if [[ $fn == $exception ]]; then
    continue
  fi
  cp "$fn" "$dir2"
done
```

Comment: [You should not rely on `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to give you parseable information. Also, you should always quote your variables when using them. Finally, you are not checking for the case where there are subdirectories involved.

Comment: Why should `ls` not be relied upon?  Please explain The cp command should indeed be quoted.

Comment: There's a link in my comment. In short, you'd be surprised what kind of characters are valid in filenames.

Comment: Unless this is a script for an end user, I generally assume that the client has some modicum of control over their environment and usually does not generate garbage filenames.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
dir1=/first/dir
dir2=/second/dir

# first loop through and find oldest file
# http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003
unset -v newest
for file in "$dir1"/*; do
    [[ -f "$file" ]] && [[ "$file" -nt "$newest" ]] && newest="$file"
done

# then loop through and perform actions on the others
for file in "$dir1"/*; do
    if [[ -f "$file" ]] && [[ ! "$file" == "$newest" ]]; then
        cp -p "$file" "$dir2"
    fi
done
```